# Date range within range and more

Tags: sql, db2

I'm attempting to come up with a SQL query that will check if a given date range lies in another, or encompasses its upper or lower boundary, or wraps it entirely. Right now I have 3 separate queries but I'm sure it can be simplified.

Any suggestions?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE
-- SURROUNDING
(DATE1 <= START_DT - 1 DAY AND DATE2 >= END_DT + 1 DAY)
-- ENCOMPASSED
OR(DATE1 >= START_DT AND DATE2 <= END_DT)
-- STRADDLED
OR(DATE1) BETWEEN START_DT AND END_DT
OR (DATE2) BETWEEN START_DT AND END_DT
```

DATE1 -> RANGE -> DATE2

START RANGE -> DATE1 -> DATE2 -> END RANGE

DATE1 -> START RANGE -> DATE2 -> END RANGE

START RANGE -> DATE1 -> END RANGE -> DATE2

And as a side note + or - one day on the given range; the Straddled can begin the last day (or day after) the range stops etc.

Comment: Post your current queries to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to test two conditions to determine if two ranges overlap. If the begin of the first is before the end of the second and if the end of the first is after the begin of the second.

```
where (
  range_1_min_date <= range_2_max_date
  and
  range_1_max_date >= range_2_min_date
)
```

Added:
To picture why this is the condition, [image] consider a base range (range_1, shown at the bottom of the diagram), and then think of all the various other possibilities for date_range_2.

Using the diagram, look at the conditions above for each of the ranges shown, and you'll see why it works.

Comment: Isn't that essentially what the between is testing?

Comment: No, the between is exactly that. It is checking that the start or end of one range is between the start and end of the other range. As such it only verifies part of the condition for overlapping ranges, and is why the other conditions are required in your example.